# Safari. Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver

I'm trying to run my Selenium test on Safari. I can run my test on FireFox and IE, it works fine, but not on safari.
So may be someone had the same issue and can tell me why it's not working and yes, I've added WebDriver to Safari Extencions: http://prntscr.com/809miw

---

I have this error:

---

```
2015-08-03 13:18:57.666:INFO::main: Logging initialized @169ms
[2015/08/03 13:18:57] [ID:69E814D] [Session Start]: Initializing Session...
[2015/08/03 13:18:58] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 39280

[2015/08/03 13:18:58] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari

[2015/08/03 13:18:58] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverChannelHandler$1 operationComplete
INFO: Connection opened

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Driver connected in 980 ms

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Closing connection

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@2038ae61

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Aug 03, 2015 1:18:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete

[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Exception in thread "main" 
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'Vitaliii-PC', ip: '169.254.8.187', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:58)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:51)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at Kodak.AutoTest.Framework.Session.Start(Session.java:117)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at Kodak.AutoTest.QBT.TC93CreateProject.main(TC93CreateProject.java:27)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:111)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:42)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.execute(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:191)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
[2015/08/03 13:18:59] [ID:69E814D] [Selenium]:  ... 7 more
```

And here is how I choose browsers:

---

```
switch(this.type)
        {
            case IE:
                File file = new File(this.config().getParam(ConfigFacade.IEDriverPath_Key));
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
                //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.logfile, ""); // TODO: here somehow redirect log to stream.
                this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            case Chrome:
                File chromeFile = new File(this.config().getParam(ConfigFacade.ChromeDriverPath_Key));
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeFile.getAbsolutePath());
                this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case FireFox:
                this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case Safari:
                this.driver = new SafariDriver();
                break;
            default:
                throw new TestException(String.format("Browser (%1s) is not implemented yet", this.type.toString()));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SafariDriver is available only for OS X. As I can see from your logs, you are trying to execute it on Windows 7.
You can check the supported operating systems and browsers here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp

Comment: So, if I don't have OS X, is there some other ways to run this script?

Comment: Well, you can always setup a virtual machine running OS X and execute it there. In my team, we are using Telerik Test Studio Framework that supports Safari, and it can be executed on Windows. You can check the framework here: http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework

Comment: well, framework it's good, but in my team, we just still creating our own framework. So using another framework it's impossible for us. So, ok, I will run my test on virtual machine. Thx for answer :)